# Update with sum

Tags: oracle, sum, sql-update

I have a table with the following fields:
ID, VALUES, VARIAB

Im trying to SUM the field VALUES, but it needs to be grouped by ID.
And the Subselect doesnt accept multiple lines. (When i use it with just 1 ID, works fine).

```
BEGIN 
UPDATE TBL2
SET SOMA =
      (SELECT SUM(x.VALUES)
      FROM TBL3 x INNER JOIN TBL2 y
     ON y.ID = x.ID
  WHERE    y.ID = x.ID AND X.VARIAB = 1
GROUP BY x.ID
   );
END;
```

Im using ORACLE DB, if anyone comment this ill be very gratefull.
Sorry for my english flaws.

Comment: Do you want to update multiple records at once? If so, use `MERGE` statement.

Comment: I alread tryied, but probably did it wrong. I did something like this:    BEGIN
MERGE INTO TBL2 x
USING TBL3 y ON (x.ID = y.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET SOMA = (SELECT SUM(VALUES);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your update statement isn't correlated - ie. your subquery has no reference to the table being updated.

You could change it to:

```
update tbl2 t2
set soma = (select sum(t3.values)
            from   tbl3 t3
            where  t2.id = t3.id
            and    t3.variab = 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

To update multiple records at once and/or do an upsert, use [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) statement like this :

```
MERGE INTO TBL2 T2 USING (
    SELECT x.id,SUM(x.VALUES) total
    FROM TBL3 x 
    WHERE x.VARIAB = 1
    GROUP BY x.ID
) T3 ON (T2.ID = T3.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET T2.SOMA = T3.TOTAL
```